# data not fetching into dropdown

Tags: php, html, frontend

I am trying to fetch some data from my db to a dropdown. But it does not work. This is my code. Thanks

```
<div class="col-md-5">
   <select multiple class="form-control" style="height: 100px" id="experienceEdit">
     <?php
         $sqlVessel = "SELECT * FROM vessel_types ORDER BY vessel_types ASC";
         $resultVessel = $conn->query($sqlVessel);

         if ($resultVessel->num_rows > 0) {
              // output data of each row
              while ($rowVessel = $resultVessel->fetch_assoc()) {
      ?>
      <option class="experienceValEdit"  value="<?php echo $rowVessel['idvessel_types']; ?>"><?php echo $rowVessel['vessel_types']; ?></option>
      <?php
            }
               } else {

               }
      ?>
```

Comment: write what fields are in your table?

Comment: @MikeFoxtech thanks for commen. `idvessel_types` and `vessel_types` only

Comment: Do you have data in the table?

Comment: yes there are 7 data

Comment: try, perhaps, connection with the base is not present    if ($conn->connect_errno) {
    printf("no connection: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
    exit();
}

Comment: @MikeFoxtech when i echo anything at `else` its working

Comment: with connection to the database there are no problems?

Comment: @MikeFoxtech yes all other my forms working ok. they fecth and show well. only this one dosent work

Comment: May or may not help your problem, but there is no need to check num rows. Just let the `while` do its thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this line.

```
  if ($resultVessel->num_rows > 0) {
```

There should be a **-**

I think this should generate some erros. Isnt it?@usinshif